# .values() syntax in DML statement

Tags: apex

I was going through a section of the code in "Advanced Apex Programming" book.

In particular I was slightly puzzled to see this code

```
List<Contact> cts = [SELECT ID,AccountId,Account.Id,Account.AnnualRevenue FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'testcontactln'];

Map<Id,Account> accountstoupdate = new Map<Id,Account>();

for(Contact c : cts)
{

if(ct.Account.AnnualRevenue == null)
{
   ct.Account.AnnualRevenue = 500;
   accountstoupdate.put(ct.AccountId,ct.Account);

}

}
update accountstoupdate.values(); //HERE
```

Can someone tell me the difference between "update accountstoupdate" and "update accountstoupdate.values()" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `accountstoupdate` is type of `Map`. DML `update` action requires an sObject or List of sObject type. `accountstoupdate.values()` gives you a list of `Account` where you can perform an `update` DML.

I'm not sure if it works without error `update accountstoupdate` as you said. This should throw an run time error since you can't perform `DML` on a `Map`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

On the first look I thought you are right, however I was not convinced and executed above code in Developer console and it worked perfectly.

I executed following code:

```
List<Contact> cts = [SELECT ID,AccountId,Account.Id,Account.AnnualRevenue FROM Contact ];  
system.debug ( 'CTS SIZE IS '+cts.size());  
Map<Id,Account> accountstoupdate = new Map<Id,Account>();  
for(Contact ct : cts){  
if(ct.Account.AnnualRevenue == null){  
   ct.Account.AnnualRevenue = 500;  
   accountstoupdate.put(ct.AccountId,ct.Account);  
    }  
}  
update accountstoupdate.values();   
System.debug('MAP IS '+ accountstoupdate);
```

And debug logs shows :

> 09:52:13.404 (404888056)|EXECUTION_STARTED   09:52:13.404
>   (404901046)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
>   09:52:13.451 (451706716)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|CTS SIZE IS 1
>   09:52:17.552 (4552772937)|USER_DEBUG|[20]|DEBUG|MAP IS
>   {001110000134hX5AAI=Account:{Id=001110000134hX5AAI,
>   AnnualRevenue=500}}   09:52:17.848
>   (4848847859)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex   09:52:17.852
>   (4852017153)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

The explanation behind this is that values of a map are stored as a list. In this scenario we are updating `accountstoupdate.values()` which will return list of Accounts.